# How can I hang the bibliography cite key into the left margin like section numbers in memoir?

Tags: bibliographies, margins, memoir, natbib

The memoir documentclass has the option `\hangsecnum` which hangs (sub)section numbers into the margin, and right aligns them to the left text margin.

I'd like to accomplish the same thing for my bibliography, where the numerical keys/labels of the form `[xxx]` are right aligned and left to the left text margin. How can I do this? I don't really see how to make a succint example, as it may prevent the solution (I'm not sure if this needs to be done in bibtex, natbib, memoir or hacked in LaTeX). Note I'm using `bibentry` so I can't have the bibitems do a negative hspace (which wouldn't scale to the amount of digits in the number anyway).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\pagestyle{companion}
\hangsecnum
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

% these are limited to the example
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} %  only to ge the header showing the margin to show
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1,
  author={me},
  title={bla},
  year={2015},
  journal={International journal of blabla}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\section{bla}
\subsection{blabla}
blablabla\cite{1}
\backmatter
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

So I'd like the [1] in the bibliography to hang left of the header's line, as with  the section number with hangsecnum (but not so extreme maybe).

Comment: As always on this site an MWE to work with would be much appreciated

Comment: @daleif Added. Needed to figure out how to make it copy-pastable without having the need for two files.

Comment: This is generally the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
% it is not memoirs version of thebibliography that is being used, but
% natbibs and its numbers setup
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\NAT@bibsetnum{\fi}{%
  \fi%
  \setlength\leftmargin{0pt}
}{}{}
\makeatother
\setbiblabel{\llap{[#1]\kern0.75em}}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need!